# Android: how to draw an ImageButton using the pressed state drawable for the focused state

Tags: android, button, background

I am trying to achieve an effect where, once pressed, an ImageButton draws with the "pressed" orange background until it loses focus (something else is touched).

StateListDrawable seems intended for this situation, because it would allow me to define how the background should be drawn for the focused state.  And it would be great if I could simply define that the background should be drawn with the pressed drawable, for the focused state.  However, I see no way to reference the default "pressed" drawable.

Any advice on how I can achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look inside the drawables folder inside the android SDK. You can find all of the nine patch images it uses by default. The ones you want are likely called btn_pressed, btn_focused etc. Or something similar. You can technically refer to them by id in your project but I believe it is suggested that you copy them into your project, because the IDs are not garunteed to stay the same.

Comment: Thank you.  I marking this as answered because it does answer my question, but it didn't actually solve my problem.  Problem turns out that the imagebutton loses focuses on the "up" event of the touch.  I would like the imagebutton to retain the focus until something else grabs it (so that it draws as focused until something else is touched).  Any advice on this?

Comment: Try calling yourButton.requestFocus() inside your onClick(View v) method of your onClickListener() for the button.

Comment: @ab11 set you button to be focusable in touch mode http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:focusableInTouchMode android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Answer (score 5):

if i understand your question maybe can help you

i do the same task defining a xml background selector, that contains drawables for each state, this file is more extensive because you can define drawables, shapes, etc... The most important feature is that you can set any drawable or shape you want...

here i defined my background selector... and i call it selector.xml and saved into drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/shape_7"/>
        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/shape_7" />
        <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/shape_6" />
    </selector>
```

later when i build the ImageButton i attach the selector mentioned above... (you can do programatically or in your xml layout)

```
ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(this);
imageButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector));
```

or the xml way

```
<ImageView
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4px"
    android:src="@drawable/switch_icon"/>
```

cheers

Comment: this is helpful, however, may main issue is that i want the selected and pressed and focused drawables to be the android default.  is there anyway to define shape_7 and shape_6 such that they use the default android drawalbes?  (when i say default android drawables, i mean the ones that are used if a custom background is not set)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in the Holo Dark theme of my app, but it doesn't have the rounded edges that I would like.

res/drawable/image_button_background.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" android:state_pressed="true"/>
</selector>
```

Use as:

```
android:background="@drawable/image_button_background"
```